# запускается и с разу же закрывается exe pyton

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Я не знаю в чем проблема, но вот мой код:

```py
import play
import pygame
circllo = play.new_image(image= "WhatsApp.jpeg",x = 0, y = -5,size= 80 )
platform = play.new_image(image= "1.jpg",x = 0, y = -250,size= 80 )
circle = play.new_image(image= "images (2).jpg",x = 0, y = -250,size= 50 )
circ = play.new_image(image= "images (1).jpg",x = 0, y = -250,size= 50 )
cir = play.new_image(image= "images.jpg",x = 0, y = -250,size= 50 )
ci = play.new_image(image= "2.jpg",x = 0, y = -250,size= 50 )
#new_circle 
#x, y, radius, color
blocks = []
#-----    
@play.when_program_starts
def start():
    platform.start_physics(stable = True, obeys_gravity = False, bounciness = 1, mass=1)
    circle.start_physics(stable = False,x_speed=35, y_speed = 35, obeys_gravity = False, bounciness = 1, mass=10)
    ci.start_physics(stable = False,x_speed=35, y_speed = 35, obeys_gravity = False, bounciness = 1, mass=10)
    cir.start_physics(stable = False,x_speed=35, y_speed = 35, obeys_gravity = False, bounciness = 1, mass=10)
    circ.start_physics(stable = False,x_speed=35, y_speed = 35, obeys_gravity = False, bounciness = 1, mass=10)
    block_x = play.screen.left+75
    block_y = play.screen.top-50
    
    for i in range(3):
        while (block_x <= play.screen.right -30):
            block = play.new_box(color = 'red', x = block_x, y = block_y, width = 110, height = 30, border_color = "white", border_width = 1)
    
            blocks.append(block)
            block_x=block_x + block.width
    
         block_x = play.screen.left+75
         block_y = block.y - block.height
    
@play.repeat_forever
def do():
    if play.key_is_pressed('d'):
        platform.physics.x_speed = 30
    elif play.key_is_pressed('a'):
        platform.physics.x_speed = -30
    elif play.key_is_pressed('w'):
        platform.physics.y_speed = 30
    elif play.key_is_pressed('s'):
        platform.physics.y_speed =-30
    else:
        platform.physics.y_speed = 0
    
    for b in blocks:
        if b.is_touching(circle):
            circle.physics.x_speed = -1 * circle.physics.x_speed
            circle.physics.y_speed = -1 * circle.physics.y_speed
            b.hide()
            blocks.remove(b)
     for b in blocks:
         if b.is_touching(ci):
             ci.physics.x_speed = -1 * ci.physics.x_speed
             ci.physics.y_speed = -1 * ci.physics.y_speed
             b.hide()
             blocks.remove(b)
      for b in blocks:
          if b.is_touching(circ):
              circ.physics.x_speed = -1 * circ.physics.x_speed
              circ.physics.y_speed = -1 * circ.physics.y_speed
              b.hide()
              blocks.remove(b)
      for b in blocks:
          if b.is_touching(cir):
              cir.physics.x_speed = -1 * cir.physics.x_speed
              cir.physics.y_speed = -1 * cir.physics.y_speed
              b.hide()
              blocks.remove(b)
      for b in blocks:
          if b.is_touching(platform):
              platform.physics.x_speed = -1 * platform.physics.x_speed
              platform.physics.y_speed = -1 * platform.physics.y_speed
              b.hide()
              blocks.remove(b)
play.start_program()
```

Либо я неправильно скомпилировал

Answer (score 1):

Из-за [изменений](https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/commit/b5d3b64485817819a399c582e3fb82dafd0a53c3#diff-5d8fe928eb0045c19b5cdf6e1edf302b9a69fbe0d8f54d445210555347d2dcb1) в модуле pymunk, `pymunk.inf` больше не работает.

Вместо него нужно использовать `float("inf")`. Замените в файле play.py в 779 строке:

```
moment = _pymunk.inf
```

на:

```
moment = float("inf")`
```